# Stating specific vector equations to be solved, very confused on what to do.

Tags: matrices, vectors

I have a question that hopefully y'all can help me with. I need help with stating the system of vector equations to be solved for the problem :
$$y=Ax^3 + Bx$$ 
as well as

$$y=Ae^x + B\sin(y) +Cx$$

I know how to solve vector equations for basic $y=mx+b$ equations but what is throwing me off is the exponents in the equations. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Substituting $y$ from the first equation, the second equation becomes:
$$
Ae^x+B\sin(Ax^3+Bx)+x(C-B)=0
$$
That is a transcendental equation that can be solved only with numerical methods.